# EKS migration from version 1.21 to 1.27 or 1.28 using Blue-Green Deployment

Tags: version, amazon-eks

Currently we are using 1.21 and it is EOS now.We have requirement of EKS migration from version 1.21 to 1.27 or 1.28 or latest using Blue-Green Deployment. Could you please kindly let me know if anyone have gone through the similar scenario, If yes please share the methodologies you have approached. It would be really appreciated if possible if could share the approach...

Thanks in advance

Looking for an approach/ method to get migrate the EKS version to 1.27 or 1.28

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for someone to share documents. Please ask a question that can be answered here, and try to include that parts you're having (most) issues with.

Comment: We are also not a team. This is a public website.